# convert separated lines in property to comma separated string in ant

Tags: xml, string, properties, ant

I have property named sound that has string [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVV60.png) and want to convert  to string like[this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apXrf.png) and again store in same property. I want do do it in ant.please help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Properties in Ant a general not mutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [loadresource](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadresource.html), f.e. create a new property foobar from your existing foo property:

```
<project>

<property name="foo" value="hotfix_master_02.sql${line.separator}hotfix_master_07.sql${line.separator}hotfix_metadb_03.sql"/>

<loadresource property="foobar">
 <propertyresource name="foo"/>
 <filterchain>
   <replacestring byline="false" from="${line.separator}" to=","/>
 </filterchain>
</loadresource>

<echo>${foobar}</echo>

</project>
```

output

```
[echo] ${foobar}} => hotfix_master_02.sql,hotfix_master_07.sql,hotfix_metadb_03.sql
```

Should also work if property foo is loaded from a file.